# Python Tkinter changing frame background colour seemingly has no effect

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm rather new to Tkinter and am attempting to put a frame within a frame, which I have successfully done, but when I attempt to change the background colour of the parent frame it has no effect.

My code is as follows:

```
import tkinter as tk

class card_game_gui:

    def __init__(self, root):
        self.pagenum = 1
        self.root = root

    def page1(self):
        page = tk.Frame(self.root, bg="blue") #<-- this line has seemingly no effect
        form = tk.Frame(page, bg="white")
        self.root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        tk.Label(self.root, text='Add player', bg="dark gray").grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="NESW")

        self.user = tk.Entry(form, bd=0, bg="light gray")
        self. user.bind("<FocusIn>", self.UserEntryFocusIn)
        self.user.bind("<FocusOut>", self.UserEntryFocusOut)
        self.user.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="NSEW", pady=5)

        user_label = tk.Label(form, text="USERNAME:", bg="white")
        user_label.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="NSEW")

        self.pw = tk.Entry(form, bd=0, bg="light gray", show="*")
        self.pw.bind("<FocusIn>", self.PwEntryFocusIn)
        self.pw.bind("<FocusOut>", self.PwEntryFocusOut)
        self.pw.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="EW", pady=5)

        pw_label = tk.Label(form, text="PASSWORD:", bg="white")
        pw_label.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="NSEW")

        tk.Button(form, text='To page 2', command=self.changepage).grid(row=3, column=0)

        page.grid(pady=50, padx=50)
        form.grid()

    def UserEntryFocusIn(self, event):
        self.user.config(bg="white")

    def UserEntryFocusOut(self, event):
        self.user.config(bg="light gray")

    def PwEntryFocusIn(self, event):
        self.pw.config(bg="white")

    def PwEntryFocusOut(self, event):
        self.pw.config(bg="light gray")

    def page2(self):
        root = self.root

        page = tk.Frame(root)
        page.grid()
        tk.Label(page, text = 'This is page 2').grid(row = 0)
        tk.Button(page, text = 'To page 1', command = self.changepage).grid(row = 1)

    def changepage(self):
        root = self.root

        for widget in root.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()
        if self.pagenum == 1:
            self.page2()
            self.pagenum = 2
        else:
            self.page1()
            self.pagenum = 1

root = tk.Tk()
card_game_gui = card_game_gui(root)
card_game_gui.page1()
root.mainloop()
```

Expected output (The blue scribbled upon area represents where the background should be, but isn't blue)

[image: Expected output]

Actual output

[image: Actual output]

Comment: Change to: `page.grid(pady=50, padx=50, sticky='nsew)`

Comment: @stovfl it makes no difference

Comment: You have to repeat this with: `form.grid(pady=50, padx=50, sticky='nsew)`

Comment: @stovfl that's worked perfectly, would you mind explaining why I needed to add the padding to `form` and not to `grid`?

Comment: ***"why I needed to add the padding to form"***: By default, `Frame` widgets resizes to the **child** size, here `form`. Adding padding, to `form` let the `page` not resize below this padding. You have to think from the **inner** to the **outer** `Frame`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The frame `page` to which you have assigned `blue` color is completely packed with the child frame `form` which has background color `white`. The area that you want to be blue is not a frame instead is the master window area from the padding to the frame `page`. So you need to configure the color of master window to `blue`.

```py
import tkinter as tk

class card_game_gui:

    def __init__(self, root):
        self.pagenum = 1
        self.root = root

        #<-- configure color of your master window
        self.root.configure(background='blue')

    def page1(self):
        page = tk.Frame(self.root, bg="blue") #<-- this line has seemingly no effect
        form = tk.Frame(page, bg="white")
        self.root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        tk.Label(self.root, text='Add player', bg="dark gray").grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="NESW")

        self.user = tk.Entry(form, bd=0, bg="light gray")
        self. user.bind("<FocusIn>", self.UserEntryFocusIn)
        self.user.bind("<FocusOut>", self.UserEntryFocusOut)
        self.user.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="NSEW", pady=5)

        user_label = tk.Label(form, text="USERNAME:", bg="white")
        user_label.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="NSEW")

        self.pw = tk.Entry(form, bd=0, bg="light gray", show="*")
        self.pw.bind("<FocusIn>", self.PwEntryFocusIn)
        self.pw.bind("<FocusOut>", self.PwEntryFocusOut)
        self.pw.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="EW", pady=5)

        pw_label = tk.Label(form, text="PASSWORD:", bg="white")
        pw_label.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="NSEW")

        tk.Button(form, text='To page 2', command=self.changepage).grid(row=3, column=0)

        page.grid(pady=50, padx=50)
        form.grid()

    def UserEntryFocusIn(self, event):
        self.user.config(bg="white")

    def UserEntryFocusOut(self, event):
        self.user.config(bg="light gray")

    def PwEntryFocusIn(self, event):
        self.pw.config(bg="white")

    def PwEntryFocusOut(self, event):
        self.pw.config(bg="light gray")

    def page2(self):
        root = self.root

        page = tk.Frame(root, bg='blue')
        page.grid()
        tk.Label(page, text = 'This is page 2').grid(row = 0)
        tk.Button(page, text = 'To page 1', command = self.changepage).grid(row = 1)

    def changepage(self):
        root = self.root

        for widget in root.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()
        if self.pagenum == 1:
            self.page2()
            self.pagenum = 2
        else:
            self.page1()
            self.pagenum = 1

root = tk.Tk()
card_game_gui = card_game_gui(root)
card_game_gui.page1()
root.mainloop()
```

**PAGE 1**

> The blue area is actually the master window (root window) region from the padding value of 50 (padx and pady) to the frame `page`.

[image: b]

**PAGE 2**

> Since you haven't given any padding to page 2 widgets, you don't have such a large master window area.

[image: page2]

I have explained the changes with some theory. I hope you understand!

Comment: Is there a way I could create a Frame (such as `page`) that does that I ask? Or would I have to change the root background colour?

Comment: Hey @Monkeybike123, there surely is a way. Add padding to you frame `form` and remove padding from the frame `page`. Don't forget to remove the color configuration for root window which is not required anymore.                                                                                                                                                          ```python                                                                                                       page.grid()
form.grid(pady=50, padx=50)                                                                                ```

Comment: What it does is, it fits the frame `page` to the master window (root) as there is no padding now, and gives padding to all the sides of the frame `form`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you don't see the change is that 'page' is hidden behind 'form'. If you want that area to be blue, try adding this line after 'root = tk.Tk()'.

```
root.config (bg = 'blue')
```

[image]

Comment: I'm a little confused, why is that `page` ends up being hidden behind `form`? Is the grey are that shows up (where I'd like it to be blue) not a part of `page`?